# How to fix "public key for centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm is not installed" in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, centos7

I am trying out the centos 7 official base image with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
```

When building the image I get a warning about a missing public key:

```
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/updates/packages/centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Public key for centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm is not installed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                               26 MB/s |  40 MB  00:01     
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Importing GPG key 0xF4A80EB5:
 Userid     : "CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>"
 Fingerprint: 6341 ab27 53d7 8a78 a7c2 7bb1 24c6 a8a7 f4a8 0eb5
 Package    : centos-release-7-9.2009.0.el7.centos.x86_64 (@CentOS)
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
```

How can I get rid of tthat warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see below the warning, the key is a file which is part of the base image. You just need to import it before yum throws that warning and does so itself.

The following Dockerfile will not throw a warning during build:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN rpmkeys --import file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7 && \
    yum -y update && \
    yum clean all
```

Answer (score 0):

**Considering** that CentOS 7 it is close to [reach the EOL](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product), however I'll share an example about how I solve the problem.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/centos/centos:centos7

# Add the gpg key for CentOS 7 and install  (fake) packages required for the image.
RUN gpg --quiet --with-fingerprint /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7 && \
    yum update --assumeyes && \
    yum install --assumeyes package-a package-b
```

Feel free to utilize this `Dockerfile` example and attach [correct packages names](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/) in order to generate a valid image.

Comment: Hello @Human, I am sharing and optional answer to the same question.